# replace String with value of properties file in java

Tags: java, string, replace, properties

I have a code to replace stream of string. I need to search a specific string that is defined in the key of properties file

```
    String result="";
        int i=0;
        while (i<listToken.size()){
            result = listToken.get(i);
            while (enuKey.hasMoreElements()) {
                String key = (String)enuKey.nextElement();
//                String value = propertiesSlang.getProperty(key);
                if (listToken.get(i).equals(key)){
                    String value = propertiesSlang.getProperty(key);
                    listToken.get(i).replace(listToken.get(i), value);
                    System.out.print("detected");
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
```

But it doesn't replace word. How I can replace words using properties.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you forgot to assign the result, using the method [set()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#set(int,%20E)):

```
listToken.set(i, propertiesSlang.getProperty(key)));
```

assuming `listToken` implements [AbstractList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html)

Answer (score -2):

Why complicate things with replace(). As far as I understand your code you can simply do -

```
String value = propertiesSlang.getProperty(key);
listToken.set(i, value);
```

I see you have modified your code again to

```
listToken.get(i).replace(listToken.get(i), value);
```

Just so that you know `String` class is `immutable`. So operations like `replace()` or `substring()` will give you a new String and not modify the original one. Get the new String and set it in your list listToken.

Comment: I just love it when people like yourself copy an existing answer and then get 'accepted'. You have no shame, ha?

Comment: Will due respect i was the 1st to answer this question. Plus OP has modified his question twice after that and I have incorporated them both in my answer. And I think you should watch you tone and do some background check before generalizing something and asking someone if he/she has no shame.

Comment: You were *not* the first, and you didn't publish your answer at least 5 minutes after I published mine. I know that cause I hanged around a bit and then left. The fact that the OP added code doesn't mean anything cause the question remained the same. The descant thing to do now is to apologize and delete your answer. But I guess that people with no shame are not descant to begin with...

Comment: And as a proof: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6086504/replace_String_with_value_of_properties_file_in_java_-_Stack_Overflow.png

Comment: I don't want to debate you on who posted answer first. Read your answer it does not answer OPs current state of question. It did the earlier version but that too is not optimized and vague. When you already have value fetched from list and stored in `value ` why would you do it again in set method?

Comment: refresh your page and see who published the answer first

Comment: "Will due respect i was the 1st to answer this question. " - and now "I don't want to debate you on who posted answer first" - that's already a proof that you're a liar. Now you're trying a different approach... well, let's continue: he's original code was: `listToken.get(i).replace(listToken.get(i), propertiesSlang.getProperty(key));` it can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29271053/revisions and it already uses the "replace" - so nothing changed fundamentally...

Comment: I hope that this will teach you a lesson not to copy other answers in the future!

Comment: I did not copy any answer. When I saw the question it was already on 2nd revision as per the link you have provided and neither did I see your answer. And still your answer does not answer OPs question.

Comment: "I didn't see" is a very poor excuse. Have a great life - discussion is over!